# Get Incoming call after crashing app twilio

Tags: ios, xcode, twilio

I need to get the incoming call after  user killed the application from running .

How can I keep registered in twilio after crashing app .

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean with manually crash the app? Are referring to the app switch in which the user can kill the app, then you are out of luck. It the user kills an app that is it. The app is removed from memory and no code is called.

Comment: ok , i can send pushnotification , can we run code on receiving notifications ?

Comment: Yes, if you send a silent push notification, If you app is not running iOS will start it and give you about 30 second before the os will suspends your app again. Be aware that the user can turn off this behavior but not allowing your app to run in the background.

Comment: Ok , but i tried that and its not let me log in with twilio . i cant get incoming calls !

Comment: No error not bedbug information, you do not give a lot information to go one. Also I have never worked with twilio.

Comment: @Devang, I guess you want to be able to receive incoming calls while your app is in background, the way Skype does? Im looking for a solution for the same problem

Comment: Yes , i must receive but when i kill app (press home button two times and kill) i cant able to receive calls

Comment: Same question I facing see my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802913/can-we-do-voip-push-notification-using-twilio-ios-sdk

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: Hi @Wos .. You can send a push notification

Comment: I already done this using push notification. when I click on notification it takes some time to login into the twilio . and till then I get the state disconnected from other device (who is calling)

Answer (score 2):

Ricky from Twilio here.

If the app is not running at all then the client cannot receive the call. One solution would be to detect the no answer on the server using the [call status information from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/HELP/faq/voice/what-do-the-call-statuses-mean). Once you see a no answer you could send a APNS message to the device, but right now there is nothing built in that would do that for you.

Comment: Hello Ricky , As you have suggested I am sending APNS (push notification) to app when calling  .. but when I click on notification it takes some time to login into the twilio . and till then I get the state disconnected from other device (who is calling) . Can you help me handle this ?