# Can we do VOIP push notification using Twilio iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, twilio, twilio-api

I have to implement App to App functionality using Twilio iOS SDK.
I have successfully implemented voice calls when the app is running.
Now I am facing a problem when the app is killed. How can I get VOIP push notifications for an incoming call?

I am referring to this link : https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/notifications/guides/sending-notifications

There is no VOIP push documentation for VOIP incoming calls.

Please provide me with some useful ideas/solutions as soon as possible.

Comment: Same here, Even I am not able to receive local notification for video call when application is in background.

Comment: @AjayGabani : you can use twilio incoming connection method for use to display local notification. I had got solution for that for voip call.

Comment: @Wos Did you implemented same case when app is killed? If yes then how did you managed pending request object or incoming request object?

Comment: Login for same as when app is running. You have just implement voip push notification when app is kill. When will you get VOIP push, you need start twilio connection and than call establish.

Comment: @Wos Are you sending a function call to server to send Voip Push when a user is calling other user

Comment: @user3354805 :  Yes. It's working like that. :)

Comment: @Wos can I know how to start twilio connection and then call establish from appdelegate when receiving void pushkit notification in app kill state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I answered over email, but thought I better include the answer here too as there were other comments.

We currently do not support VOIP push with [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/ios). We do have some recommendations on how to deal with the application when it is not active. Please take a look at this article and implement the suggestions: https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-client/twilio-client-ios-sdk-background-best-practices

Comment: Ok. How can we handle client connection when incoming call take place? I means that when voip push notification come and we tap on notification and establish a incoming connection. Right I manage voip push notification but problem is that when some one call me , Voip push notification fire to receiver user and when receiver user tap on push notification he/she can not talk each other because twilio client is not listening incoming connection. I handle a token expiration time and regenerate token.

Comment: Example : we can not get call in didReceiveIncomingConnection method when i am tap on push notification. Even if User 2 take place a out going connection and User 1 is not receive call.

Comment: The article suggests you send a notification when the device receives the `didReceiveIncomingConnections` callback. Is that what you're doing right now?

Comment: Yes. -didreceiveIncomingConnection method is not call when I am tap on VOIP push notification. How can we manage that? Using VOIP push notification.

Comment: But Twilio Client does not support using VOIP push notifications. When Twilio Client is connected and in the background, when it receives a call it will call `didReceiveIncomingConnections` and that is the point at which you should send a notification to the user. When the user opens the application, you then need to display a UI for the user to accept the incoming call.

Comment: I manage UI for accept and reject call. But problem is that UIDevice is not connecting to receiving call.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to handle all the Twilio Client setup and connection?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114842/discussion-between-wos-and-philnash).

Comment: Hi @philnash i have use twiliovoiceclient and twilioclient both in one call but i found i am not able to do call with twilio voice client it may be conflicts

Comment: @GamiNilesh I'm not sure what you're asking there. It's probably better to open a new question on StackOverflow than drop in at the bottom of an answer for an old question though.

Comment: Any suggestion on the below question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41498841/trigger-an-incoming-voip-call-using-callkit-and-twilio-video-api